# Malloc with pointer tag structure

Tags: c

I am creating a simple graph with nodes and edges. I got the functionality going but got some memory bugs.

I have a typedef struct in header file:

```
typedef struct Graph_s* Graph;
```

And implementation in c. file:

```
struct Graph_s {
    Node* nodeArray;
    Edge* edgeArray;  
    size_t edges;
    size_t nodes;
};
```

And function for construction:

```
Graph create_graph() {
    Graph newGraph = malloc(sizeof(Graph)); 

    newGraph->edges = 0;
    newGraph->nodes = 0;
    return newGraph;
}
```

The line `Graph newGraph = malloc(sizeof(Graph))` gives: `Invalid write of size 8` from Valgrind.

Comment: Some style suggestions: `typedef`s for pointer types are not recommended, and `typedef`s for struct types are unnecessary. I'd just declare `struct Graph { ... };` and refer to the struct as `struct Graph`, and to the pointer type as `struct Graph*`. Thus: `struct Graph newGraph = malloc(sizeof *newGraph);`. And a function with no parameters should use `(void)`: `struct Graph create_Graph(void) { ... }`

Comment: Thanks for the input! That defenitely keeps things clearer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`malloc(sizeof(Graph))` is only allocating enough memory for a pointer. Change it to `malloc(sizeof(struct Graph_s))`.

Comment: Pulled it off! Thank you Brett!

Comment: Even better: `Graph newGraph = malloc(sizeof *newGraph);`

Comment: And this is yet another example of where typedef'ing everything can and will make things less clear than otherwise, leading to bugs because you can't even understand what the types you defined are.